# How to deploy Node.JS app with Angular MySQL on AWS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, angularjs, amazon-web-services

I have a working node js app (angular + MySQL) which i can run on local host using XAMPP (Apache) with no issue but i want to upload it on AWS or any similar web service. I have tried to upload it on AWS but receiving error messages. Please help

Comment: Hey Ash... it would be helpful if you posted the error messages, how exactly you were uploading to AWS, etc.  Is there a specific article you were following instructions from?  If so it might be helpful to post that as well.

Comment: What are the services you have used in AWS? is it EC2?